# Multiset Partition Using Linear Arithmetic and Z3

Tags: z3

I have to partition a multiset into two sets who sums are equal.  For example, given the multiset:

```
1 3 5 1 3 -1 2 0
```

I would output the two sets:

```
1) 1 3 3
2) 5 -1 2 1 0
```

both of which sum to 7.

I need to do this using Z3 (smt2 input format) and "Linear Arithmetic Logic", which is defined as:

```
formula : formula /\ formula | (formula) | atom
   atom : sum op sum
     op : = | <= | <
    sum : term | sum + term
   term : identifier | constant | constant identifier
```

I honestly don't know where to begin with this and any advice at all would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Also, I would like to know how to declare a negative number such as (assert (= x -1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

1- Create a 0-1 integer variable `c_i` for each element. The idea is `c_i` is zero if element is in the first set, and 1 if it is in the second set. You can accomplish that by saying that `0 <= c_i` and `c_i <= 1`.

2- The sum of the elements in the first set can be written as `1*(1 - c_1) + 3*(1 - c_2) + ... +`

3- The sum of the elements in the second set can be written as `1*c1 + 3*c2 + ...`

Comment: Wow, that is very clever.  I was trying something similar by using booleans instead of 0-1 integer variables.  It was illegal in the grammar but I wanted to start somewhere.  Many thanks!!!

Comment: So this leaves me with one issue.  The subtractions and multiplications are illegal in the grammar.  I worked around this by creating a pair of 0-1 variables for each c_i such as c_1 and c_9 where c_1 and c_9 are both 0 or 1 and c_1 + c_9 = 1.  Then I wrote out the two sums as `(assert (= sumSet1 (+ (* c1 x1) (* c2 x2) (* c3 x3)...` and `(assert (= sumSet2 (+ (* c1 x9) (* c2 x10) (* c3 x11)...`  Now, the multiplications are illegal but they can be expanded to additions.  The only problem is how to deal with negative numbers in the input.  They can't be expanded to additions.

Comment: You can move them to the other side of the equality. I mean, `a - b = c` is equivalent to `a = b + c`

Comment: Hi Leonardo!  I'm not sure I follow.  Right now I can expand a sum like this: `(assert (= sumSet1 (+ (* c1 x1) ...` into, say, `(assert (= sumSet1 (+ (+ x1 x1 x1) ...` for c1 = 3.  But if the input constant c1 equals a negative number then this trick won't work.

Comment: If `c1` is negative say `-3`, you move it to the other side of the equation, and use the same trick you used for positive values: `(assert (= (+ sumSet1 x1 x1 x1) (+ ...`

Comment: Oh. [Hits forehead with hand.]  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

While SMT-Lib2 is quite expressive, it's not the easiest language to program in. Unless you have a hard requirement that you have to code directly in SMTLib2, I'd recommend looking into other languages that have higher-level bindings to SMT solvers. For instance, both Haskell and Scala have libraries that allow you to script SMT solvers at a much higher level. Here's how to solve your problem using the Haskell, for instance: https://gist.github.com/1701881.

The idea is that these libraries allow you to code at a much higher level, and then perform the necessary translation and querying of the SMT solver for you behind the scenes. (If you really need to get your hands onto the SMTLib encoding of your problem, you can use these libraries as well, as they typically come with the necessary API to dump the SMTLib they generate before querying the solver.)

While these libraries may not offer everything that Z3 gives you access to via SMTLib, they are much easier to use for most practical problems of interest.